# How to initialize a second order direct form 1 filter for no transient upon filter reset

Tags: discrete-signals, digital-filters

I need to calculate **initial states** of a second order direct form 1 (DF1) filter that result in zero transient **upon reset (initialization)**. I'm starting with setting filter input (x) equal to filter output (y) (desired steady state condition) which results in 1 equation but **4** unknowns (filter states s1 to s4), hence no unique solution. Any thoughts?

'filter reset' here means reseting all delay blocks with a set of initial states (s1 to s4)

Lets say this DF1 is realization of a lowpass filter on the actuator commands to an aircraft. If we need to reset the filter (for whatever reason) while flying (varying inputs to the filter), ideally we'd like to see no transients in filter output (commands to aircraft) upon reset. I can probably define "transients" here as y(n)=x(n) AND y(n+1)=y(n) (I think). In other words, upon filter reset, output is equal to input and output derivative is zero.

[image: Direct Form 1]

Comment: Well, a filter reset means that you lose the values of states s3 and s4.  They are a function of the past samples, and theoretically all the way back to $-\infty$.  But if you're IIR impulse response is short, you can reconstruct those states to a close value by just going back a finite number of samples.

Comment: So do you have access to past samples of the input $x[n-1]$, $x[n-2]$, *and* output $y[n-1]$, $y[n-2]$?  If you do, then resetting states is, of course, no problem.  But if you do not have access to those four numbers, you know the most current input value $x[n]$ and that's it, I don't know any rhyme or reason you could use to guess at what the filter states should be.

Comment: Apologies @robertbristow-johnson. I misstated the original question which is now corrected. I need to estimate initial states for a given set of filter parameters (a1, a2, b0, b1 and b2) to guarantee no transient upon filter reset.

Given the under constraint nature of this problem, I'm thinking of one possible solution as setting initial values of s2=s3=s4=0 and solve for s1 in this equation: y=x = b0*x+b1*s1. Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "filter reset". If you want to avoid transients you need to make an assumption about the signal and what causes the transients. In many cases that's a DC offset (in which case, you can certainly per-calculate the states)

Comment: @Hilmar 'filter reset' here means reseting all delay blocks with a set of initial states (s1 to s4).

Comment: By "zero transient" do you mean "no deviation from how the filter would have behaved if it had been running on the signal forever"?  If so -- move do a different universe with different physical laws.  If you mean something _else_, like the transient is unnoticeable to humans, or any glitch is below some threshold, then what you want _may_ be achievable.  You need to define what sort of transient is acceptable, and what sort of signal you're dealing with.

Comment: @TimWescott. Lets say this DF1 is realization of a lowpass filter on the actuator commands to an aircraft. If we need to reset the filter (for whatever reason) while flying (varying inputs to the filter), ideally we'd like to see no transients in filter output (commands to aircraft) upon reset. I can probably define "transients" here as y(n)=x(n) AND y(n+1)=y(n) (I think). In other words, upon filter reset, output is equal to input and output derivative is zero.

Comment: Sorry -- please **edit your question** with this information (it's a Stackexchange thing -- Stackexchange wants complete questions and complete answers, with no necessary details buried in the comments).

Comment: Understood @TimWescott. Just updated the original post. Thanks for the guideline. I'd love to hear your thoughts after this clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends a bit on the type of signals you are working with. In many cases the problematic property of the signal is a large DC offset which will create an artifact akin to the step response of the filter.

In this case it's easy to find the states. Let's assume a constant DC input

$$ x[n] = x_0$$

The steady state response of the filter is also a constant which is the input multiplied with the DC gain of the filter, i.e.

$$y_{ss}[n] = \frac{b_0+b_1+b_2}{a_0+a_1+a_2} x_0$$

Fortunately for Direct Form I the states are simply the past inputs and and outputs, so we have

$$s_1 = s_2 = x_0\\ s_3 = s_4 = \frac{b_0+b_1+b_2}{a_0+a_1+a_2} x_0$$

Obviously that only works if the source of a transient is a DC offset. The same method can be applied to other types of signal as well but you do have to make some assumptions about that signal.

Comment: Thanks @Hilmar. I think your response is exactly in the right direction. Just to to make this post more comprehensive, I'd like define the 'no transient' 'constraint' upon rest as: y(n)=x(n) and y(n+1)=y(n) (no derivative), if that makes sense?

Comment: Just updated the original post as per TimWescott's request. I was wondering if you have any additional thoughts?

Comment: Well, there is no all-size-fits all solution for this. You can optimize for certain assumptions around either the signal, the filter, or both. But without any assumptions, there isn't a whole lot you can do.