# How to initialize states of second order direct form 2 transposed filter

Tags: discrete-signals, filter-design, digital-filters

**Background**

This question is an extension to [this post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/87747/54225). I need to calculate states ($S_1$ and $S_2$) of a second order direct form 2 transposed (DF2T) filter that result in minimum 'transient' when filter is 'reset' with an DC offset input. To clarify the problem statement:

- 'Reset': reseting delay block to the 'desired' states
- 'Desired States': States that result in minimum 'Transient' upon 'reset'
- 'Transient': variation in output due to 'reset'

Lets say this DF2T is realization of a lowpass filter on the actuator commands to an aircraft. If we need to reset the filter (for whatever reason) while flying (varying inputs to the filter), ideally we'd like to see no transients in filter output (commands to aircraft) upon reset.

**Calculations**

Based on what I've learned from this [this post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/87747/54225) I can readily calculate $S_1$:

From the DF2T diagram below:

$S_1= y[n] - b_0x[n]$

In steady state we have:

$$y_{ss}[n] = \cfrac{b_0+ b_1 + b_2}{1 + a_1 + a_2} x[n]$$

Assuming $x[n] = x[0]$ (DC offset), we get:

$$S_1=\left[\cfrac{b_0+ b_1 + b_2}{1 + a_1 + a_2} - b_0 \right] x[0]$$

**Question 1:**

$S_2$ though on the other hand seems to be more challenging to calculate since it is not directly (without any delay) linked to either input/output. This is were I need some help to understand how to approach the problem and calculate 'appropriate' value for $S_2$ to minimize transients upon filter initialization.

**Question 2:**

How can I impose a constraint on output 'derivative' (e.g. zero derivative) upon reset to calculate $S_1$ and $S_2$?

[image]

Comment: On a side note. I've tried using $ and \ to type formula in latex but have not had any success. Is there any tutorial link available by any chance?

Comment: Just click “*edit*” on your question and you can see how I achieved that feat :)

Comment: https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1722/50076

Answer (score 1):

The process is similar to the one in the other question, you just have to add the definitions of the states as a function of input and output. I'm going to define the states BEFORE the delays and not after as in the drawings, simply because it's a bit cleaner that way, but it makes no difference in the result. We call the state related to $s_2$, $q[n]$ and the one related to $s_1$ $p[n]$, i.e. $s_2[n] = q[n-1]$ etc.

We can now write the coupled difference equations as

$$\begin{aligned} q[n] &= b_2 \cdot x[n]-a_2 \cdot y[n] \\
p[n] &= b_1 \cdot x[n]-a_1 \cdot y[n] + q[n-1]\\
y[n] &= b_0 \cdot x[n] + p[n-1]\end{aligned}$$

We'll use the suffix $ss$ to denote the steady state response for a DC input for each signal and state. We start with a steady state input $x[n] = x_{ss}$. The output is given by the DC gain of the filter, i.e.

$$y_{ss} = \frac{b_0+b_1+b_2}{a_0+a_1+a_2} x_{ss}$$

We can then work our way through the state variable equations

$$\begin{aligned}q_{ss} &= b_2 \cdot x_{ss}-a_2 \cdot y_{ss} \\
p_{ss}&= b_1 \cdot x_{ss}-a_1 \cdot y_{ss} + q_{ss}\end{aligned}$$

An that's it !